# Get only custom models in Alfresco Community using Rest API

Tags: rest, alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I'm tring to get only custom models (Types of document) deploied in Alfresco community using rest API by following url: http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/dictionary
The problem it retun a big JSON contending information about all models (workflow forms, defaut types, aspects).

I would like to fiter only custom models (Types of document) and yours properties in my query.

How can i do it ?

Thanks!
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that endpoint supports filtering. 
I'd suggest doing one of your own since custom models should be easy to find (simply remove the standard Alfresco ones, you know their namespaces).

http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/references/RESTful-DictionaryDictionaryGet.html

Comment: I can apply a filter using: http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/defclasses?nsp=namespace:mymodel         but it return all results when the values fitred not exists.